# How do I open an application protocol in browser from a href attribute?

Tags: javascript, lodash, protocols, href, url-scheme

I am trying to call an app protocol from a href browser url, e.g href = "mailto://", and it  should open the mail client e.g on windows.

However, I am setting up my html with lodash templates, and the href attribute somehow always sets a "http://"  before the url..:  "http://mailto://" therefore it does not work anymore, so in lodash templates, I am trying string preparation to just give me the protocol, but I get an empty href attribute then as a result... why? This is my lodash snippet:

```
<p id="element<%- el.id %>" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
    <a href="<% el.link.substr(0,7) == 'http://' ? el.link.replace('http://', '') : el.link %>" alt="favApps" target = "_blank"><%- el.title %></a>
</p>
```

EDIT: It was my fault, as I was using a third-party plugin, there was a security-reason that blocked opening of app protocols, thats why `http://` was added and `#blocked` to unknown protocols...

Comment: Can you not just use "mailto:emailaddress"why the "//" ?

Comment: it was a security reason thing from a third party library... using this in normal html file and it works as it should...

Answer (score 0):

I was using a third-party plugin, there was a security-reason that blocked opening of app protocols, thats why http:// was added and #blocked to unknown protocols...